# Oracle 10g. Errors with calling procedures

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to run simple procedures and functions but get the same sort of error (Oracle 10g). What's wrong here?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE hello_world
IS
  l_message
  VARCHAR2 (100) := 'Hello World!';
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_message);
END hello_world;
/

BEGIN
   hello_world;
END;
/
```

Error message:

```
ERROR at line 9: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" 
7.   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_message);
8. END hello_world;
9. /
10. BEGIN
11.    hello_world;
```

Comment: Can you remove the / and try again?

Comment: Yes. I remove both / and then get this: ERROR at line 10: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" 
1. CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE hello_world
2. IS
3.   l_message

Comment: Your code block works fine for me. I'm using 11g, but syntactically that should work in 10g.

Comment: Do you call it from command line or some tool like sql developer?

Comment: I run this from Chrome using Web Interface, not Command Line. That's pretty weird. Is there any sort of hack I can apply to this to make it run? We have to use Oracle 10g only.

Comment: I have executed this code and got the point, pls see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are executing all of this code together. You should first execute create or replace procedure part and after the procedure is created, execute an anonymuous block:

```
BEGIN
   hello_world;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now! I wonder why it didn't work earlier with the other sort of procedures. Just checked - it works on them too. It means that I have to create code blocks independently and run them independently.

Comment: Yes, done it. Unfortunately, I have not enough points to add to your reputation.

Comment: Oh, it is not important at all. Thanks!